# I have a problem launching Payday 2

Tags: technical-issues, payday-2

This started happening a couple days ago. When it try to launch the game from steam it tries to open but fails and displays nothing, so I tried opening it from the game folder. It displayed the following error :

"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close application."

I found a guide saying I should uninstall two windows updated but I didn't have them installed in the first place.
I've also tried reinstalling the game and verifying the game files (it shows no problems).

This problem also occurs when I try to start Teamspeak 3 and a previous version of skype (new version works fine).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? I was using the Wolfpak UI which stopped working on a Payday 2 update

Comment: No, I never used any mods and I don't think that this is a problem with the game itself.